# Can I apply torch.isin() to each row in 2D tensor without loop?

Tags: pytorch

I have two tensors.

```
tensor_1 = tensor([[10,  8,  7],
                   [ 4,  5,  9]])

target_tensor = tensor([[ 8,  8,  6, 11,  0],
                        [ 7,  2, 10,  4,  5]])
```

and torch.isin(tensor_1, target_tensor) returns

```
tensor([[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False]])
```

I want to apply isin to each row and get result like below

```
tensor([[False,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False]])
```

I can do this using for loop, but I don't want to use loop.

```
tmp_result = torch.zeros_like(tensor_1, dtype=torch.bool)

for i in range(tensor_1.size(0)):
    tmp_result[i] = torch.isin(tensor_1[i], target_tensor[i])
```

How can I apply torch.isin() to each row in 2D tensor using GPU without loop?

Comment: `functorch.vmap(lambda t1, t2: torch.isin(t1,t2))(tensor_1, target_tensor)` returns the correct result, but warns that it's not yet optimized in the latest Pytorch version.